# Approximation of $ \ t\log(1+x)$

Tags: convex-optimization, transformation, linear-approximation

I have following optimization problem:

max $t\log(1+x) : t \land x$ are variables.

I know that we can approximate $\log(1+x)$ by DC programming or Geometric programming and make the optimization problem to be convex, but in my case, I have another variable $t$ multiplying with $\log(1+x)$, how can I make my problem to be convex?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remember that $t\log(1 + x) = \log(1 + x)^t = \frac{1}{\log_{1 + x}10 \therefore \ \text{If} f(x) = log(1 + x) \implies f'(x) = \frac{1}{x \In(b)}$

Comment: Remember that

$$t\log(1 + x) = \left\{\log(1 + x)^t \mid \ \text{If} \  f(x) = \log(1 + x)^t \implies f'(x) = \frac{1}{t(1 + x) \ \text{In}(10)}\right\}$$

Comment: if there is no relationship between $t$ and $x$, and $t$ is not bounded by anything (i.e. you are not optimizing over the interval closed in $t$), you get infinity. If $t$ is bounded it should take the highest possible value and then optimize the log separately. However, if there is a relationship between $t$ and $x$, you need to mention what it is exactly.

Comment: I have edited my question and added the complete formulation, please have a look now, thanks.